# Installing and setting up hadoop 2.7.2 in stand-alone mode

Tags: hadoop, installation

I'm installing hadoop now using the following link :

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation

I have Question on installing and setting up hadoop platform as stand-alone mode.

First making input file in Standalone operation, this site write command as follows :

```
$ mkdir input
$ cp etc/hadoop/*.xml input
$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
$ cat output/*
```

what is this processing?? running example??

and I issue those commands, I got the error as displayed in the image below :

[image]

what is problem??

Comment: Based on the error, I think you used the pseudo distrusted XML files for the Standalone section.

Answer (score 0):

> what is this processing?? running example??

Those commands didn't process anything seriously rather than that, just executing a predefined example available with hadoop jar file to make sure you have installed & configured the setup properly.

As assumed that you were in the directory **"/"** while executing the following commands :

1) `$ mkdir input` : creating a directory called **input** under root directory **/**

2) `$ cp etc/hadoop/*.xml` input : Copying the hadoop conf files (*.xml) from **/etc/hadoop** to /input

3) `$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`  :

Executing an inbuilt example class shipped with hadoop libraries. This example do extract the parameter starts with ***dfs*** from all the hadoop xml conf files located under the directory ***/input*** and write the result into the directory **/output** (implicitly created by hadoop as part of execution).

4) `$ cat output/*` : This command print all the file contents under the directory /output in terminal.

> what is problem??

The problem you are facing here is the "input path". The path is vague and it was not resolved by hadoop. Make sure you are running hadoop as standalone mode. And finally execute the example by giving absolute path (for both input and output) as follows :

`$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar grep /input /output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`

Comment: On HDFS, there is a difference when you add the leading slashes to the input and output. `mkdir input` makes the directory on the local filesystem, in the current directory, the Hadoop jar, on the other hand, expects HDFS paths

Comment: Yes i understood that **/** means root context of hadoop. But in the above said scenario, hdfs wasn't used directly since all the commands were executed and the input/ouputs are mapped over local file system.

Comment: You might want to update your answer, then because you said *creating a directory called input under root directory*, when, it's actually the current folder, which might be the root directory, but not necessarily. And if you look at the error image, an HDFS path is used, and the `/user/root/input` path cannot be found *on HDFS*

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, so far my knowledge, hadoop standalone mode executes the job using local file system instead of hdfs since all the components are running as single jvm process. For reference, kindly go through this link : http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/other-programming/excerpts/hadoop-tdg/installing-apache-hadoop.html

And I agree with your comment which added under the question. That is what I wanted say, but you won. :)

due to the misconfiguration of mode, the NameNode service was looking for input from hdfs instead of local file system "/input" prefixed with the username "/root".

Comment: I do think the default `hdfs-site.xml` uses `file://` as the hdfs path, so you would be correct, however the configuration xml files weren't provided in the question

Comment: Yes. that is a good catch. Please ask him to provide the conf xml's content.